# Before and after Member update

Tags: python, discord.py

Everything works great except for the before avatar and the after avatar, they just don't send. No errors, just nothing.

````
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    guild = after.guild
    guild_id = after.guild.id
    cursor.execute('SELECT channel_id FROM logchannel WHERE guild_id = %s',
                   (guild_id,))
    result1 = cursor.fetchone()
    if result1 is not None:
        channel_id = result1[0]
        channel = discord.utils.get(guild.channels, id=channel_id)
        if  before.display_name != after.display_name:
            await channel.send(f"Nickname of {before.name} changed from {before.display_name} to {after.display_name}")

        if before.activity != after.activity:
            await channel.send(f"{after.name}'s activity changed from {before.activity.name} to {after.activity.name}")

        if before.avatar_url != after.avatar_url:
            await channel.send(f"{after.name}'s avatar has changed from {before.avatar_url} to {after.avatar_url}")```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`on_member_update` won't be called for avatar changes.  Instead [`on_user_update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_user_update) is.  This is because if the bot shares more than one guild with another user, we only want to get a single event.

Comment: I just saw this, so sorry for the late response. I didn't know that, so thank you!